# Convert text to xml using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd

I have a text file as given below:

`value1 value2  value3     value4`

I want to convert it as following xml using XSLT

```
 <values>
    <value>value1</value>
    <value>value2</value>
    <value>value3</value>
     <value>value4</value>
   </values>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT doesn't entertain Text to XML conversion. You can do the other way though(XML to Text).

Comment: @Linhamurthy CS: The guy is using Java, so why are you assuming s/he's still on XSLT 1.0? OK, when people don't say which version, that often means they aren't aware of the difference, but since they need XSLT 2.0 to solve the problem, and it's available in their environment, your response saying "can't be done" is unhelpful and incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelKay : Thanks, Dr.Kay.. That was my ignorance. I wasn't aware of this capability of XSLT2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can edit your input such that it contains a root element, and a tab character as a separator, such as below:

```
<root>value1    value2  value3  value4</root>
```

then, you can apply the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <values>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'&#x9;'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </values>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenizeString">
        <!--passed template parameter -->
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                <value>
                    <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/>
                </value>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                    <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$list = ''">
                        <xsl:text/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$list"/>
                        </value>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and produce:

```
<values>
   <value>value1</value>
   <value>value2</value>
   <value>value3</value>
   <value>value4</value>
</values>
```

Comment: This is an XSLT 1.0 "solution" that doesn't solve the question as given. See my response for a much more concise and complete XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: @Joel M. Lamsen: Suppose I want to add different node name theses values? How can I do that.

Comment: please post this as another question as this may require a different solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:template name="main">
 <values>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('input.txt'), '\s+')">
   <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </values>
</xsl:template>
```